# How can I draw a Cayley graph for $S_3$?

Tags: tikz-cd

I need to draw the Cayley graph for S_3 with the presentation $S_3 = (s,t | s^3 = t^2 = 1, tst = s^2)$. I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}
    $$\begin{tikzcd}
        &&&&& 1 \\
        \\
        &&&&& 4 \\
        \\
        \\
        &&& 5 &&&& 6 \\
        \\
        3 &&&&&&&&&& 2
        \arrow[from=1-6, to=8-11]
        \arrow[from=8-11, to=8-1]
        \arrow[from=8-1, to=1-6]
        \arrow[from=3-6, to=6-4]
        \arrow[from=6-4, to=6-8]
        \arrow[from=6-8, to=3-6]
    \end{tikzcd}$$
\end{document}
```

but the output is not something close to what I'm searching for:
[image]

The other Cayley graphs I found around the internet are either extremely complicated, thus I have no idea on how to modify them, or they are not what I am looking for. Any help in adding the curved arrows, moving the arrowheads on the vertices and styling the nodes as in the picture is welcome.

Comment: Should this be made up of equilateral triangles? Then, `tikz-cd` might not be the best tool for it.

Comment: Ideally, yes. The 1-2-3 and 4-5-6 triangles should be unilateral.

Comment: I'd just draw it manually in TiKz, seems easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pos`itions of the pics are manually adjusted so that they visually look centered along the path.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >={Straight Barb[angle=45:3pt 3]},
  label 0/.style={anchor={#1}, outer sep=+.3em},
  label 1/.style={anchor={180+#1}}]
\foreach[count=\INNER from 0] \RADIUS/\LIST in {1/{4,6,5}, 2/{1,2,3}}
  \foreach[count=\CNT from 0] \ELEM in \LIST
    \path (90-\CNT*120:\RADIUS) coordinate (\ELEM)
      node[label \INNER=90-\CNT*120, circle, inner sep=+.15em] {\ELEM};

\draw[pos=.53] (1) -- pic{arrow} (2) -- pic{arrow} (3) -- pic{arrow} cycle
               (4) -- pic{arrow} (5) -- pic{arrow} (6) -- pic{arrow} cycle;
\foreach \A/\B in {1/4, 2/6, 3/5}
  \draw[pos=.6, bend left=30] (\A) to pic{arrow} (\B) to pic{arrow} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do this with `tikz-cd`, but it requires some manual adjustment of the spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}}, postaction=decorate, -, thick}
}
\newcommand{\arrowboth}[1][]{\arrow[#1, bend left=15, myarrow]\arrow[bend left=15, myarrow, from=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm, arrows=myarrow, column sep=9mm, cells={nodes={draw, circle, inner sep=2pt}}]
&[4mm]&[-4mm]1\arrow[dddrr]\arrowboth[d]&[-4mm]&[4mm]\\[4mm]
&&4\arrow[dl]\\
&5\arrow[rr]&&6\arrow[ul]\\[-4mm]
3\arrow[uuurr]\arrowboth[ur]&&&&2\arrow[llll]\arrowboth[ul]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```